# Declaring a static member array dimension with another static member

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, static

Declaring a static member array dimension with another static member is allowed in the Apple clang compiler(version clang-1400.0.29.102) **but not** in the Ubuntu c++ compiler (version 11.2.0-19ubuntu1). It seems that the compiler assumes the values of the variables used in the variable `strings`' dimensions are 1 at declaration but attempts to evaluate them at definition.

Is there a way to get the Ubuntu compiler to "wait" and not declare `strings` until the variables used in its dimensions are defined?

```
class MyClass
{
    // declarations
    static const int i_num_strs;
    static const int i_str_lens;
    static const char strings[i_num_strs][i_str_lens];
};

// defintions
const int MyClass::i_num_strs = 5;
const int MyClass::i_str_lens = 6;
const char MyClass::strings[i_num_strs][i_str_lens] = 
{
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five"
}
```

When compiled on MacOS there is no issue but when compiled on Ubuntu the following "*conflicting declaration*" error:

```
test_test.cpp:8:43: error: size of array ‘strings’ is not an integral constant-expression
    8 |     static const char strings[i_num_strs][i_str_lens];
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
test_test.cpp:8:31: error: size of array ‘strings’ is not an integral constant-expression
    8 |     static const char strings[i_num_strs][i_str_lens];
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~
test_test.cpp:14:41: error: size of array ‘strings’ is not an integral constant-expression
   14 | const char MyClass::strings[i_num_strs][i_str_lens] =
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
test_test.cpp:14:29: error: size of array ‘strings’ is not an integral constant-expression
   14 | const char MyClass::strings[i_num_strs][i_str_lens] =
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~
test_test.cpp:21:1: error: too many initializers for ‘const char [1][1]’
   21 | };
      | ^
```

**Disclaimer:** This is for an application where dynamic memory allocation is not desired and MACROS are not "allowed"

Comment: You can't hide the variables that need to be `constexpr` in the .cpp file. The values have to be specified in the header.

Comment: Your code won't compiler for many different reasons. Missing semicolons, missing/inconsistent `const` qualifiers, and the `strings` member is either an array or it isn't. And did you forget to finish your last sentence?

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for the heads up. While those were issues, the point in the first statement should be evident: this behavior is allowed in one compiler but not the other.

Comment: @Brothaman Just initialize the data members inside class. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qxYv3jW89). See also dupe: [static constant members for array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710039/static-constant-members-for-array-size).

Comment: @Brothaman Also, when defining the members outside the class you forgot to add `const`. For example `const` is missing in `int MyClass::i_num_strs = 5;`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking in "C" style arrays (specialy for strings), this is C++.
You can use constexpr + string_view to define strings that are constant at compile time.

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 5> strings
    { 
        "One","Two","Three","Four","Five" 
    };
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << MyClass::strings[2] << "\n\n";

    for (const auto& value : MyClass::strings)
    {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::array` is a red herring. This works because you replaced the size constant with a magical number.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For me not really,  it is just as "magical" as initializing a const value to 5.  And in the rest of the code you can use `MyClass::strings.size()` to refer to that magic number, so it is still single source of information.

Comment: And yes : `static constexpr std::size_t number_of_strings{ 5ul };   static constexpr std::string_view strings[number_of_strings] {...}` would also have worked.

Comment: Mhm, my point is, `std::array` vs plain array is a style choice here. It has nothing to do with fixing OP's error, but the answer (at least to me) implies otherwise.

Comment: Fair enough, my answer is mostly there to show the use of `constexpr` to avoid linking issues.